# How to get attribute value from Extension object (Python cryptography)?

Tags: python, cryptography, x509certificate

I want to access name attribute from Extension object.

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import ExtensionOID

l_certificate = rgetattr(self.l_config_json, 'web_interface.certificate.certificate')
d_certificate = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(str.encode(l_certificate))
ext = d_certificate.extensions.get_extension_for_oid(ExtensionOID.EXTENDED_KEY_USAGE)
extendedKeyUsage = ext.value
print(extendedKeyUsage)
```

Result:

```
<ExtendedKeyUsage([<ObjectIdentifier(oid=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2, name=clientAuth)>, <ObjectIdentifier(oid=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1, name=serverAuth)>])>
```

How to access name attributes(clientAuth and serverAuth) from result??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the goal, you are just wondering how to access the attribute values? These can be derived by looking at the class definitions in `site-packages/cryptography/x509/extensions.py` and is a foundational skill (i.e. read the source code).

What I do is pretty straight forward:

```py
# common to cryptography.x509.extensions.ExtensionType
data = {
    'critical': ext.critical,
    'name': ext.oid._name
}
# extension specific attributes
if isinstance(ext.value, cryptography.x509.extensions.ExtendedKeyUsage):
    data['key_usages'] = [x._name for x in ext.value or []]
```

which produced

```
 {'critical': False,
  'key_usages': ['serverAuth', 'clientAuth'],
  'name': 'extendedKeyUsage'}
```

instead of the `repr` you have, and cannot parse I guess?

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting and storing in `'ext'` is a list. Access the individual items in the list by either iterating through it or by directly referencing its location. For eg: for `"clientAuth"` try using `ext[0].value`

```
extendedKeyUsage = ext[0].value

print(extendedKeyUsage)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).